# dense rank function in R with maximum number of rows with the same rank

Tags: r, dense-rank

[image]

I want to rank a column with no gaps and also with a limit for maximum numbers of rows of the same rank after which even the value is the same there should be the next number as rank. how can we do this in R?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: added an image for reference, thanks!

Comment: Images are not the correct way to share data. We cannot copy data from an image. Please read the link I shared earlier.

Comment: somehow not able to insert this table as it is and that is why pasted it as an image.

Comment: Try `dput(head(YourDataFrame))`.

Comment: tried this as well, not working

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way -

- First we create a unique id for each consecutive number using `rleid` function.
- Within each `id` we create group of `limit` rows and assign `TRUE` for the 1st row.
- Use `cumsum` to create the final result.

```
library(dplyr)

limit <- 3

df %>%
  mutate(id = data.table::rleid(V1)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result = row_number() %% limit == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  transmute(V1, result = cumsum(result))

#      V1 result
#   <dbl>  <int>
# 1    11      1
# 2    11      1
# 3    11      1
# 4    12      2
# 5    12      2
# 6    12      2
# 7    12      3
# 8    12      3
# 9    13      4
#10    13      4
#11    14      5
#12    14      5
#13    14      5
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14))
```

Comment: thanks! it is working but a confusion there are some more columns as well in the data frame, how can I retain those columns as it is without changing anything?

Comment: Use `mutate` instead of `transmute` to retain the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```r
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(rep(11,3), rep(12, 5), rep(13, 2), rep(14, 3)))

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  # mutate(rank = dense_rank(V1)) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(count = (row_number() - 1) %/% 3 + 1) %>%
  group_by(V1, count) %>% 
  mutate(rank = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-count)
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 13 x 2
      V1  rank
   <dbl> <int>
 1    11     1
 2    11     1
 3    11     1
 4    12     2
 5    12     2
 6    12     2
 7    12     3
 8    12     3
 9    13     4
10    13     4
11    14     5
12    14     5
13    14     5
```